# Lightning Experience Visualforce Component has extra Padding in Spring '17 and thus making VF pages look awkwardly spaced

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, spring17

When we place a Visualforce component container in Lightning Page, the current release displays them correctly without extra spacing, thus allows a developer to control the look and feel of the Visualforce Page interface.

But in Spring '17 Pre-release org, the Visualforce Component container has extra padding on left/right/top/bottom, with dark gray background color, thus placing the existing Visualforce Pages to look awkwardly spaced out.

P.S.- Already talked to Salesforce Support, and the support wouldn't take a notice of this issue unless I'm on a Premier Support plan, and guided me to developer forums to post it there where many Salesforce Reps keep an eye out for developer related issues/queries and could internally open the issue when needed.

** EDIT ** - Still no success on resolving this ...

I really hope someone from SFDC team sees this, I don't know where else I can take it up to, but the mingling of Home Page Layout with Visualforce Components and Lightning Component is all messed up due to this, a Table view of Lightning Component has NO Left/Right Padding, and it mixes well with component borders, while VF Component has so much padding with gray background, it just put the table view in VF out of fit n finish UI, with nothing much a developer can do to fix it.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This isn't a question. It should be reported as a Spring 17 bug to Salesforce.

Comment: Actually I already did that, and they wouldn't acknowledge it unless I'm a premier support customer and as usual was guided to developer forums. And I don't know where else I could get Salesforce Team to get attention to this issue, which may break lot of Visualforce customizations.

Comment: Do you think that would have been helpful information to include when posting your "question"?

Comment: Yes ... my bad, I've added the info now.